# Centering input element with position: absolute in IE11 in a table

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I'm having some trouble understanding why IE11 doesn't keep text-align: center in mind when using position: absolute.  I created a JS fiddle.  Basically I have two checkboxes that I wanted stacked on top of each other in the center of a table cell.

```css
table {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>
    <input id="box1" type="checkbox">
    <input id="box2" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3f5993oc/
This works in chrome, but not in IE.  I'm looking for a solution that works in both browsers.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for IE, you need to use position:relative/absolute, coordonates and reset margin https://jsfiddle.net/3f5993oc/1/

Comment: I know it sounds strange like why would anybody do this, but I have my reasons.  One of the checkboxes will be disabled and the actual checkbox will have opacity: 0.  We're using CSS3 using ::before.  It's complicated to me, but I tried to simplify this as much as I could before posting here what the intention is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for IE, you need to use `position:relative`/`absolute`, coordonates and reset `margin`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

#box1 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0.175em auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>
      <input id="box1" type="checkbox">
      <input id="box2" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```